# select average data from database group by index and show it into datagridview

Tags: vb.net

I have datatable with 4 columns (Nama, CoIndex, RowIndex and Nilai).
I want to select the average data (Nilai) from database group by same CoIndex, RowIndex and show it into DataGridView

I'm not really sure how to do or approach this. Any help is greatly appreciated.

```
Dim cmd As MySqlCommand
Dim rs As MySqlDataReader

cmd = New MySqlCommand("select from `tb_kuisioner` ", Connector)
rs = cmd.ExecuteReader
If rs.HasRows Then
    While rs.Read
        If Val(rs("rowIndex")) > Val(rs("colIndex")) Then
            dg1.Item(rs("colIndex"), rs("rowIndex")).Value = Val(Format(rs("nilai"), "0.000"))
        Else
            dg1.Item(rs("colIndex"), rs("rowIndex")).Value = Val(rs("nilai"))
        End If
    End While
    rs.Close()
```

Comment: What errors do you get when you run your code?

Comment: Are you trying to group in the SQL query?

Comment: You should first build a query that returns what you need. Then put the data in the database. Some thing like: select CoIndex, RowIndex, avg(Nilai) from tb_kuisioner group by ColIndex, RowIndex

Comment: it works.... thank you